# Adsense in wordpress excerpt

Tags: css, wordpress, adsense

We are trying to insert adsense ads in between wordpress excerpt. But ads are overlapping in posts. How to fix this issue with css. My test site is [Tiny Life Boat](http://tinylifeboat.com/)

```
<div style="max-width:700px; align:center; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px;">my ad code</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have all your articles floating left. So you need to set the clear to both for your adv wrapper to get the correct result.

```css
.adv-wrapper {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="adv-wrapper">
  Your add goes here!
</div>
```

And please don't use the `center` tag its deprecated [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_center.asp)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Now we removed "center" tag. Any suggestions for overlapping?

Comment: Yes, as I said before add a div wrapper to your ads that has float:none.

Comment: Added, but no action.

Comment: I updated my answer please use ```clear: both;``` instead of ```float: none;```